# How do I write alt text for an icon inside a button tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accessibility, alt

I'm using react and I have a table with a Delete action column. I'm displaying a delete button in each row and want to have alt text for the entire button but I'm not sure how to do this since  does not come with an alt option. I tried the below code but it doesn't work. I know I'm not doing it correctly so I wanted some guidance.

Also, I'm using the iconify library for my icon.

```
const DelButton = () => {
  return (
    <Link to="/someLink">
      <button aria-label="Delete" title="Delete">
        <Icon icon="gg:trash-empty" alt="Delete"/>
      </button>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

Comment: title attribute should show a text on mouse hover. Can you check what is the resulting HTML when viewing the page ?

Comment: @Jaay it does show the text on hover but my issue is that the alt does not work. When the icon is not present, it will show the button background without displaying the alt text. When it should just be showing the alt text

Comment: alt attribute is standard for <img> tag, after checking on iconify there is no such thing as alt text. You can try to use the 'title' attribute instead of alt bu I'm not very familiar with react

Comment: @Jaay I want to use alt for accessibility purposes so I don't think title will cut it. But thanks for trying!

Comment: `alt` itself is only valid on `<img>`, but your button already has `aria-label`, which could be considered the alternative text for icon-buttons. When the button gets focussed, this is what is exposed to assistive technology. You could also move the `aria-label` from the button to the icon, which would have the same result.

Comment: Would you mind describing in your question how you are verifying if it works?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Have you actually tried this with a screenreader? (Although not all screenreaders behave the same way, nor do all browsers in conjunction with a screenreader.) As far as I understand it, both `aria-label` and `title` should be sufficient to get a screenreader to announce that text to users in conjunction with the button (and I believe `aria-label` takes priority of the two, but would need to look it up in the ARIA specification to be sure).

Answer (score 3):

Using `aria-label` on the `button` element should be sufficient.

You should remove the `alt` attribute from your `Icon` element. If it doesn't render to an `img` element, then it's not valid HTML anyway.

`aria-label` not only takes precedence over the `title` attribute in the [accessible name computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.2/#terminology), but it also enjoys quite a bit [better browser support](https://www.deque.com/blog/text-links-practices-screen-readers/).